# Allies Cards in Sickbay/Brig

Tags: battlestar-galactica, exodus

Last weekend my group played Battlestar Galactica's Exodus Expansion using the Ionian Nebula option. In a determined moment of the game, an Ally Card was located at the Sickbay (it was Simon O'Neill, but the same applied to Dr. Cottle in a later moment in the game). My question is, considering that players cannot move their characters on their own to the Sickbay and an encounter with Allies only occurs after the Movement Step of a player, when an encounter with an Ally in Sickbay or Brig should happen? My thougths are:

- Players sent to Sickbay can encounter an Ally in Sickbay if they stay in Sickbay in his Movement Step (this is possible?). If they move out from the Sickbay, they do not encounter the Ally.
- Players sent to Brig must encounter an Ally in Brig while they are in the Brig

Is that correct?

Comment: You can stay in the sickbay if there's an ally, but each sickbay ally moves you out anyway, so it's up to you. You can avoid encountering a brig ally if you can use a critical situation and get out of the brig before your main action.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Samthere but I believe that it is only possible to not encounter an ally in Brig if someone move you out from the Brig before your turn. The encounter happens before the Action Step, and, since you cannot move, you will encounter the ally. I already accepted an answer, but discuss this seems good to future visitors!

Comment: That's right in general, but Critical Situation uses your movement (rather than an action) so whatever you do with that happens during your movement step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your guess is correct.

> At the end of a player’s Movement step, if his character is in the same location as an ally token, he must encounter that token’s corresponding Ally Card before proceeding to his Action phase.

In the brig, you cannot leave during your movement step voluntarily. Leaving will normally occur as a result of using the action on the brig space. You still have a Movement step, so you're going to encounter the ally before you take an action from a card or on the brig space.

> Players may move out of “Sickbay” without difficulty, but
>   not the “Brig.” They may only move out of the “Brig” by
>   passing the skill check listed on the location.

In Sickbay, you wait until your turn and would have to decide to remain there during your Movement step. It says "may move out", so you're clearly allowed to stay. This means, however, that you may be starting your next turn there as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why they would be treated any different.  The rules say

> At the end of a player’s Movement step, if his character is in the
>   same location as an ally token, he must encounter that token’s
>   corresponding Ally Card before proceeding to his Action phase.

Just because you don't leave those areas voluntarily doesn't mean you don't have a Movement step.  At the point in your turn where Movement would occur, if you end that step in the same location as an ally, encounter them.  Also

> A player may only encounter an ally on his turn and may encounter only
>   one ally per turn.

So clearly you do not encounter the ally at the time that you are sent to Brig or Medbay, but wait until the Movement step of your own turn.